# Which would be better? Storing/access data in a local text file, or in a database?

Tags: sql, database, text-files, words, local-storage

Basically, I'm still working on a puzzle-related website (micro-site really), and I'm making a tool that lets you input a word pattern (e.g. "r??n") and get all the matching words (in this case: rain, rein, ruin, etc.). Should I store the words in local text files (such as words5.txt, which would have a return-delimited list of 5-letter words), or in a database (such as the table Words5, which would again store 5-letter words)?

I'm looking at the problem in terms of data retrieval speeds and CPU server load. I could definitely try it both ways and record the times taken for several runs with both methods, but I'd rather hear it from people who might have had experience with this.

Which method is generally better overall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fast retrieval you certainly want some kind of index. If you don't want to write index code yourself, it's certainly easiest to use a database.

If you are using Java or .NET for your app, consider looking into [db4o](http://www.db4o.com). It just stores any object as is with a single line of code and there are no setup costs for creating tables.

Answer (score 6):

The database will give you the best performance with the least amount of work.  The built in index support and query analyzers will give you good performance for free while a textfile might give you excellent performance for a ton of work.

In the short term, I'd recommend creating a generic interface which would hide the difference between a database and a flat-file.  Later on, you can benchmark which one will provide the best performance but I think the database will give you the best bang per hour of development.

Answer (score 0):

Storing data in a local text file (when you add new records to end of the file) always faster then storing in database. So, if you create high load application, you can save the data in a text file and copy data to a database later. However in most application you should use a database instead of text file, because database approach has many benefits.